# Spring Boot PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver not finding the expected Resources

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, classloader, resource-loading

When trying to fetch resources using the tried-and-true

```
Resource[] esResources = ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(resourceLoader)
                .getResources("classpath*:/es/" + storageFilename + ".json")
```

(resourceLoader is the default @Autowired provided by spring boot)

esResources returns empty when the file is clearly there in the classpath under /BOOT-INF/classes/es/

Bigger mystery is that the code works in a separate repo of ours, running the same spring-boot version (spring-boot-starter-parent 2.4.5).

Stepping both repos through the debugger, I found a diff at [this step](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/71036e7da52c546b513ba946cf9f4eada278c5f3/spring-core/src/main/java/org/springframework/core/io/support/PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver.java#L337) within `PathMatchingResourcePatternResolver`-- the one that works is using `TomcatEmbeddedWebappClassLoader`, while the "broken" one is showing `ClassLoaders$AppClassLoader`. Not sure if this is a red herring though.